# Switching between multiple Cameras using Emgu CV

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, emgucv

I have a quick question: I need to switch between the two camera on a tablet. Front and Back. By default, the Front camera is always used by Emgu CV.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There is a different constructor. I was building upon the 7 line demo for Emgu CV.

Using the correct overloaded constructor, this is what did the trick for me:

```
    private Capture _capture;

    private void InitCapture(Int32 _camIndex) {         
        try {
            if (_capture != null) {
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;               
            }

            _capture = new Capture(_camIndex);
            Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt) {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg) {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
        ImageBoxCapture.Image = frame;
    }

    private void CharmsBarBase_ButtonTop01Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        InitCapture(0);
    }

    private void CharmsBarBase_ButtonTop02Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        InitCapture(1);
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: Hello. I can't pass Mat result from QueryFrame to Image<Bgr, Byte>. Which version of Emgu are you using? i've tried with 3.1.0 and 3.4.3

Comment: @Joster It has been a very long time. I no longer am working in that project or any other of the same nature.